# how to configure run in GWT project from maven

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have problem with run GWT project made from maven. I don't know what to do to start this. Run button is disabled.
[I attach screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQUpn.jpg)

Project was created by Create "Maven Project", I also have installed GWT plugin

Answer (score 0):

Based on your inputs I will suggest you to confirm following two things

1. Use Google Web Toolkit is checked

   right click on project --> Google --> Web Toolkit --> check Use Google Web Toolkit & give correct location of default GWT SDK
2. Sample Argument for running application

   -war *path_to_your_target_war_folder* -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl *landing_html_file* -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -superDevMode *entry_class_location*

Change all variables by correct values, list of variables and example values is as follows

- *path_to_your_target_war_folder*: \Workplace\source\appName\target\appName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
- *landing_html_file*: index.html
- *entry_class_location*: com.test.myapp.Main